# Comment with //// without space

Tags: tslint

I want to enable comments without space in tslint if comment starts with 4 slashes.

Rule: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/comment-format/

I've tried

```
"comment-format": [true, "check-space", { "ignore-pattern": "//" }],
```

but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> Exceptions to `"check-lowercase"` or `"check-uppercase"` can be managed with object that may be passed as last argument.

It seems one cannot attach ignored patterns to `"check-space"`.

Comment: So, there 's no way to do it?

Comment: @Qwertiy As far as I can tell, without ugly disable/enable comments for the rule, not really. I am having the same issue trying to mark logical sections of my code but the linter complains about comments that start with `//===`. An alternative that might work for you if you need it for that purpose as well: one line full with slashes, the second line `// Section name` and the third line for with slashes again. Unless, of course, you're having issue with something different.

Comment: No, I have the other problem. I'd like to use `////` for temporary commenting some blocks of code.

Answer (score 0):

add next rule to tslint.json:

```
"comment-format": [false, "check-space"]
```

Comment: Read the first sentence of the question.

Comment: Ironically, this was the answer I was looking for.